# Show results of fgetc as character on screen

Tags: c

I am trying to debug the following code:

```
int check_file(FILE* file)
{
  int c;
  int nl = '\n';

  while((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
  {
      if (c == nl) return 0;
  }

  printf("\n ERROR EOF \n");
  return 1;

}
```

when it gets error and returns 1, I would like to know the reason.

I thought about printing on screen the character read in the variable "c", before I get the error (so I can understand in which part of the read file is the error located) but this is an integer.

Is it possible somehow to print in on screen as character?

Thanks

Comment: would it be possible to show the file position before it gets the error in terms of LINE and COLUMN numbers?

Comment: Most likely you're getting to `return 1;` because there is no newline in your file.  That in itself doesn't necessarily mean "error".  Are you sure your files has at least one newline?  Try adding a check `if ferror(file) printf("ferror\n");` before `return 1;` to see if there really was an error.

Answer (score 2):

printf("%c\n", c);

Answer (score 1):

You don't know you are getting an error.  Most likely, you are just reaching the end of the file.  You should call feof() or ferror() to determine why fgetc() is returning no more data.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is terminating on End Of File (EOF), and, while you can print the character read before it, that generally won't help you.  If you want to do something different at EOF, do that.  In other words: if EOF is an error, then "in which part of the file" is always at the end.

To get a character from an integer, use `(char)some_int`, and to output a character, use [f]putc or `printf("%c", some_int)`.

Comment: hi, is there some way to "see" with an editor like vi or something else where the EOF character is located?

Comment: It is not a character, it is a stream state.  You've reached the end of the file.  You already know where that's located.

Comment: asdf: fgetc has more possible return values ("error codes") than there are possible characters to read.  EOF is one of these, and can never exist in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

putc and fputc both take an integer argument.